# Создание объекта по ссылке PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Читал что такая запись выведет **deprecated**:

```
class A{}
$obj = &new A;
```

Но попробовал у себя на хосте и ничего не увидел (хотя все ошибки и предупреждения включил). Не суть!

Вопрос такой: какая разница создания объекта по ссылке и без?

P.S Очень интересная вещь получилась

```
$obj = new A;
xdebug_debug_zval('obj');
///obj:(refcount=1, is_ref=0), object(A)[1]
$obj = &new A;
xdebug_debug_zval('obj');
///obj:(refcount=1, is_ref=1), object(A)[1]
```

Я не понял каким образом `is_ref=1`, когда `refcount=1` (обычно `is_ref=1`, когда `refcount>=2`)?

Еще интересный момент:

```
class A{}
$obj = &new A;
xdebug_debug_zval('obj'); ///obj:(refcount=1, is_ref=1), object(A)[1]
$alter = &$obj;
xdebug_debug_zval('obj'); ///obj:(refcount=2, is_ref=1), object(A)[1]
unset($alter);
xdebug_debug_zval('obj'); ///obj:(refcount=1, is_ref=0), object(A)[1]
```

Смысл верхнего примера в том что мы привязали к созданному объекту переменную, а потом отвязали свежеиспеченную ссылку, сделано для того чтобы проверить будет ли `is_ref=1` или нет, как мы видим он обнулился, но почему не ясно, мы с оригиналом ведь ничего не делали =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Только на днях переводил [соответствующую главу](http://php.net/manual/ru/oop4.newref.php).

Если кратко, то `new` возвращает копию, а не ссылку и если использовать конструкцию `$a = &new Foo()`, то ссылка на него в глобальном массиве `$globalref` НЕ будет указывать на тот же объект, что и `$a`.

Кроме того, исходя из документации, создание по ссылке более ресурсоемкий процесс.

Поведение `xdebug_debug_zval` я бы объяснил так:

```
$obj = &new A;
```

`new A` создает экземпляр класса, передает его копию оператору `&`, который генерирует на него ссылку и передает далее оператору присваивания.

То есть в `$obj` у нас хранится ссылка на копию инстанцированного класса `A`. Отсюда получается, что, фактически, переменной, содержащей этот класс не существует. Есть только ссылка на участок памяти, где он расположен.

**UPD**

Вот что получается.

1. Создается объект и создается на него ссылка - `refcount=1`. То есть вот этот `&obj` является ссылкой. Отсюда `is_ref=1`.
2. Создается ссылка на ссылку `$alter`, счетчик ссылок инкрементируется - `refcount=2`. Она тоже ссылка, отсюда `is_ref=1`.
3. Вы удаляете ссылку на объект, на который существует 2 ссылки. Счетчик ссылок уменьшается на единицу И(!!!) последняя переменная, которая ссылается на этот объект автоматически перестает быть ссылкой, так как она последняя. Если вы знакомы с *nix, то это практически аналог hardlink.

Попробуйте вот такой код.

```
$a = 'a';
$b = &$a;
$с = &$a;
xdebug_debug_zval('a');
xdebug_debug_zval('b');
xdebug_debug_zval('c');

unset($a);
xdebug_debug_zval('b');
xdebug_debug_zval('c');

unset($b);
xdebug_debug_zval('c');
```

**END UPD**

PHP 7

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in
>   **[...][...]** on line **6**

PHP 5.3-5.6

> **Deprecated**:  Assigning the return value of new by
>   reference is deprecated in **[...][...]** on line **6**

Comment: А как объясните выводы функции `xdebug_debug_zval('obj');`

Comment: @MaximPro а что конкретно вам в нем не понятно?

Comment: я писал что не понятно =)

Comment: @MaximPro Еще раз обновил. Вроде теперь самое то.

Comment: Ха, ну блин это все равно смешно:"Создается объект и создается на него ссылка - `refcount=1`. То есть вот этот `&obj` является ссылкой. Отсюда `is_ref=1`.". Почему смешно? Ну потому что я не видел такого ни разу, даже то же самое создание переменной!. Никогда при создании переменной вы не увидите `refcount=1, is_ref=1`. Обычно когда существует ссылка в одном экземпляре то `is_ref=0`. Вы пробовали мой последний код? `is_ref` - указывает является эта переменная жесткой ссылкой так? Ну а как ссылка которая одна может являться жесткой?

Comment: Мне непонятно! Именно мой последний код отображает мое недоумение. Мне реально не понятно!
Единственное объяснение почему при наличии единственной копии refcount=1, is_ref=1 это то что сборщик мусора не обновил последнее значение, ибо как показано в моем примере после создания профилактической копии и ее же удалении все успешно встает на места. Но это лишь мое предположение

Comment: @MaximPro Ничего смешного и непонятного. Сборщик мусора тут совсем не при чем, тут работает механизм подсчета ссылок. Сколько раз вы создали ссылку на объект - столько у вас на него ссылок и есть - это `refcount`. Изначально вы создали объект по ссылке - значит эта переменная `$obj` является ссылкой aka `is_ref`. Когда же вы начинаете удалять ссылочные переменные, идет контроль, что бы хотя бы одна переменная была "типа" не ссылка.на самом деле это условность, поскольку все переменные хранят указатель на структуру памяти, просто так принято, что ОДНА из ссылок как бы ГЛАВНАЯ и не совсем ссылка

Comment: @MaximPro это работает аналогично хардлинкам в linux. Если файл один, то он - файл. Если на него создали хардлинк - этот хардлинк вроде как такой же файл, но он ссылка, хотя по факту, что изначальный фалй, что хардлинк - суть абсолютно одно и то же. Удалите изначальный файл и его хардлинк останется единственным указателем на данные на диске, то есть самим файлом.

Comment: Я вас понял, ваши комментарии стали самодостаточными чтобы понять мне ваш ответ =)
P.S Да про смешно, я так для громкости сказал, конечно ничего тут смешного нет

Comment: И еще для уточнения напоследок! Когда мы создаем объект по ссылке - выделяется опредленная память, а потом к этой области памяти привязывают переменную, так?

Comment: @MaximPro Сначала выделяется память, потом в ней создается необходимая структура данных, потом в таблице переменных создается связь конкретной переменной с конкретной областью памяти. Если создавалась по ссылке, то с флагом `is_ref=1`, если нет, то с `is_ref=0`. Это если совсем упрощенно.

Comment: А если не упрощенно? Вкратце!

Comment: @MaximPro если не упрощенно, то рекомендую почитать исходники движка, либо задать вопрос в группе рассылки разработчиков. http://news.php.net/php.dev

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.Проверьте свой текст в посте там немного криво написано. Например: "Отсюда получается, что, фактически, переменной, содержащей этот класс не существует". Вероятно вы имели ввиду: "Отсюда получается, что, фактически, переменной, содержащей экземпляр класса не существует".
P.S Вроде еще что-то видел

Answer (score 0):

У вас версия php ниже 5.3.0 с 5.3.0 будет выведенно предупреждение что этот метод deprecated, так как в версии выше 5.3.0 объект создаётся по ссылке автоматически, а начиная с 7 версии вы получите parser error.

Comment: версия 5.6, но вопрос не про ошибку

Comment: не вижу прецедента ес честно в твоем посте : `refcount` (счетчик ссылок), содержит количество имен переменных , которые указывают на данный контейнер zval , `is_ref` и представляет булево значение, указывающее, является переменная частью "набора ссылок" или нет . Все это работает для оптимизации памяти , поэтому , удалив ссылку ты как бы рекурсивно поднимешься вверх удаляя все ссылки но сам объект остается, поэтому `refcount=1` и ссылок нет `is_ref=0`

Comment: Проведи несколько тестов с переменными и функцией `xdebug_debug_zval('obj');`, потом пиши, если вы не видите то может не стоит отвечать или писать?
P.S Я провел кучу тестов и для меня значение
`refcount=1, is_ref=1` как минимум странно! Почему я писал в вопросе!